# Function is differentiable at a point so its differentiable in a region from the point

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential

Given some function $f: I \subseteq\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, Which is differentiable twice at some point $a\in I$.
Can one say that there is a region around the point where the function is differentiable twice, without any other information?

so I assume that its true because if we look at the first derivative which is:

$lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac {f(a+h)-f(a)}h $ then obliviously we can "take" h to be smaller as we want and then I can assume that if the limit exists then it exists at some region of that point a.

so I guess the same goes for the second derivative.

Comment: How do you even define twice differentiable in a single point? If we have a function that is only differentiable in a single point, than the first derivative is only defined in this single point, and taking the derivative of that again is kind of useless.

Comment: @Dirk I didn't defined the function to be differentiable *only* at a single point, I defined some function which can be differentiate twice in some point a.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f\colon\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ a continuous function which is differentable nowhere, let $F$ be a primitive of $f$ and let $g(x)=x^2F(x)$. Then $g$ is differentiable: $g'(x)=2xF(x)+x^2f(x)$. And $g'$ is differentiable at $0$. But that's the only point of $\mathbb R$ at which $g'$ is differentiable.

Comment: But because differentiable is defined by a limit, then if we can say the limit exists for 0, cant we say the limit exists in a region around zero?

Comment: I am puzzled by your comment. Did I not prove that that does **not** occur? Short answer: no, you **cannot** say that.

Comment: +1. Nice construction.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you.